# Using Kafka in a resquest/response scenario inside a REST web service

Tags: java, spring, rest, apache-kafka, message-queue

I am currently building a REST web service that needs to communicate with Kafka in a request/response pattern. (I know that Kafka is not really designed for that).

1. Client calls the REST web service.
2. REST web service publishes a message to Kafka
3. On the other side of Kafka, an app consumes the message and publishes the response back to Kafka
4. (inside the same request as #2)REST web service listens to Kakfa and wait for response corresponding to the request
5. REST web service returns the response to the client

Steps 1 to 3 seems pretty easy but I'm struggling with step 4.

My idea was to propagate an ID in each message so that I could retrieve the response corresponding to the request.

However, I have a hard time figuring out how to set up the listener on the REST web service. How can the listener returns the message to the controller?

Answer (score 0):

i think is better just create a topic for each user, then the user can send a message to another service, such message is like:

```
{
user:"myUserName"
data:"data of message"
}
```

then the service just need to push to the topic "user.myUserName"
Then from the web client just need to be subscribed to "user.myUserName" (with a consumergroup configuration, this just for read only the newest messages )...

i think the best way is just implement websocket and then push/read by that way ;)

Bye and good day.